# JComboBox - How to render names for time values

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to display a `JComboBox` that shows the text values but stores the actual int values for the user to select for session timeout values.

```
private static final String[] SESSION_TIMEOUT_OPTION_NAMES = new String[]{
    "5 Minutes", 
    "10 Minutes", 
    "15 Minutes", 
    ...
};

private static final Integer[] SESSION_TIMEOUT_OPTION_VALUES = new Integer[]{
    TimeConstants.FIVE_MINUTES, 
    TimeConstants.TEN_MINUTES, 
    TimeConstants.FIFTEEN_MINUTES, 
    ...
};
```

I know this can be done with a `ListCellRenderer` but the only way I could see it working is with a big mapping Basically alongs the lines of:

```
sessionTimeoutJComboBox.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<Integer>()
{
    private DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(...)
    {
        JLabel jlabel = (JLabel)defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(...);

        for(int x=0; x<SESSION_TIMEOUT_OPTION_VALUES.length; x++)
        {
            if(SESSION_TIMEOUT_OPTION_VALUES[x] == value)
            {
                jlabel.setText(SESSION_TIMEOUT_OPTION_NAMES[x]);
                return jlabel;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid mapping");
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Btw the reason I want to do this is so that I can just do

`(int)sessionTimeoutJComboBox.getSelectedItem();`

and not have to care more than that.

Comment: Do not use a cell renderer to generate the strings.  It will break clipboard operations and accessibility.  (Clipboards and screen readers can read the String form of a model's values, but cannot intuit what a renderer draws.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use enums:

```
private enum TimeConstants {
    FIVE_MINUTES("5 Minutes", 5),
    TEN_MINUTES("10 Minutes", 10);

    private final String text;
    private final int value;

    private TimeConstants( String text, int value ) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

And heres how to use them with JComboBox:

```
TimeConstants[] constants = {TimeConstants.FIVE_MINUTES, TimeConstants.TEN_MINUTES};
JComboBox<TimeConstants> combo = new JComboBox<TimeConstants>(constants);
System.out.println( "Selected value: " + ((TimeConstants)combo.getSelectedItem()).getValue());
```

Comment: This would be my preferred solution as well; however, OP wants to be able to cast the selected item to an `int`, which will not work in this case.

Comment: If you would add a `.getValue() ` it should return the int almost directly...?

Comment: I can't believe enums never crossed my mind. I guess I've passed my coding limit for the day...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map` instead of doing the mappings manually. i.e.:

```
Map<Integer, String> timeoutOptions = new HashMap<>();
timeoutOptions.put( TimeConstants.FIVE_MINUTES, "5 Minutes");
...
```

and then in your renderer you could just do this:

```
sessionTimeoutJComboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(...)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent( ... );
        label.setText( timeoutOptions.get( value ) );
        return label;
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually you can't do because when you try to get the list of values from the hashmap to set into the jcombobox you'll lose the ordering. And creating a comparator brings you worse off then the original solution (it's not alphabetical). Well I guess you could store the values in an array as well but that defeats the whole purpose of this exercise and I believe you're almost worse off for a smaller list because the code is now a lot more complex (ie less obvious)... Good idea, and it looked good when I first thought about, it's just that when I tried to instantiate the jcombobox it didn't work.